# Grails Rest controllers and foreign keys

Tags: grails, orm, foreign-key-relationship

I have created two domain class named `City` and `Address` in Grails 3:

```
class City {
    Long    id

    static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

    static mapping = {
        id generator: "increment"
    }
}

class Address {

    Long id
}
```

I have created two controllers for these classes. The controllers just extend the `RestfulController` class. I have created the following URL mapping:

```
    group("/api") {
        "/city"(resources: 'city') {
            "/addresses"(controller: 'address')
        }
        "/address"(resources: 'address')
    }
```

The idea being that I can access the addresses belonging to a city (with id = 1) via `localhost:8080/api/city/1/addresses`. Unfortunately, I always get *all* addresses and not only the ones belonging to the given `City`. If I break on the `index` method of the `AddressController` I see that the  `params` given to the method indclude a `cityId` which contains the id of the City passed in the query. However, it seems that the id is not picked up during the database query. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I need to add a `belongsTo` / `mappedBy` or a `City` to the `Address`?

Comment: Also add the Controller `AddressController` to the question? If it extends `RestfulController` then you have to override the method `listAllResources()`

Comment: Well, it does not. So it is necessary to override the method, there is no alternative?

Comment: For a `RestfulController` yes that method needs to be overridden to have something like `Address.findAllByCity(cityInstanceFromCityId)`